# gcloud add tag to specific Cloud Run revision

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I'm wondering how to add a tag to a specific, already existing Cloud Run revision which already has a tag.

For example:

1. I have a running revision tagged with the word "green".
2. I have another running revision with no tag, that is the latest revision.
3. I switch the tag of the "green" build to "blue".

Is the flow above possible with the `gcloud run services update` command? Or some other command? It seems like `gcloud run services update` only affects the latest revision.

Comment: So when i check you can do this using both `update-traffic` and `update` command but the issue is it starts to serve the traffic as well. Is this what you need? Or are you looking to tag it without that revision serving any traffic something like what a label does?

Comment: I'm wondering if we could use `update-traffic` or `update` and specify which revision gets updated (preferably based off of the tag of that revision).

Comment: `gcloud run services update-traffic hello --to-revisions=hello-00001-cmk=100 --region=us-central1`  this should be the best way to do what you want. So here what you should do is mention the revision name which could be a older one and mention the traffic percent if you want that to take full traffic mention `[revision-tag]=100` if you use `set-tag` flag then it will work in a different way that is what i understand. If this is what it works let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcloud run services update-traffic` has flags for updating traffic tags.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the specific revision to update with update-traffic? Or is it only the latest revision?

Comment: `gcloud run services update-traffic --set-tags=TAG=REVISION`. I don't think there's anyway to point a tag to another tag though, you have to provide the revision name.